# Tensor multiply along axis in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

The problem I have using tensorflow is as follows:

For two tensors

```
[[x11,x12...],[x21,x22...],...[xn1,xn2...]]
```

and

```
[y1,y2,...yn],
```

I want to multiply them along axis 0 to get

```
[[x11*y1,x12*y1...],[x21*y2,x22*y2...]...]
```

For example, for 
`[[1,2],[3,4]]` and `[1,2]`, I want to get the result tensor `[[1,2],[6,8]]`.

The real scenario is that I have two tensors A and B shaped (batches,height,width,n_channels) and (batches,1). Both are tensors defined in tensorflow. For each image of A in the batch I want to multiply it with the corresponding value in B.

Comment: And where is your code?

Answer (score 3):

Given a 2-dimensional tensor `x` and a vector `y`, you just need to do:

```
result = x * tf.expand_dims(y, axis=-1)
```

Or, if you like it more:

```
result = x * y[:, tf.newaxis]
```